# Hibernate 6.4.2 to 6.4.4 entity's id changes?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I can get the identity of the entity before Transaction is committed in Spring JPA.
The change from spring-boot 3.2.3 to hibernate 6.4.4 was made through @TransactionalEventListener (phase = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMIT) so that the id could not be imported before the entity was committed.

Is there a solution in relation to this?

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}

public class Event {

    private A a;
}

...
@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMMIT)
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    event.getA().getId(); // id was exist in hibernate 6.4.2, but not exist in 6.4.4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).